# Cross-Domain JavaScript запрос для получения XML с сервера

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно из некого локального файла index.html получить данные с сервера, посредством JavaScript. Сервер может возвращать только XML, но на сервере, я могу создать любой JavaScript скрипт и произвольную страничку .html. Как мне поступить ?

Comment: а хедеры вы можете генерировать на сервере ?

Comment: Нет, мне выделили одну папку, в которую я могу поместить только .js и .html.

Comment: чтобы crossdomain нужно чтобы сервер на который посылаются запросы возвращал разрешающие хедеры, иначе никак.

Comment: Можете про хедеры по подробнее ?

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/). Пример: http://jsfiddle.net/DFcUE/

Comment: прокси что-ли ?

Comment: @eicto, не только. YQL (Yahoo Query Language) позволяет фильтровать результаты отдаваемые любым REST API. То есть можно например не только получить XML, а сделать выборку. Ну и соответственно дает возможность производить cross domain запросы.

Comment: ну по сути фильтрующий прокси. не очень хорошая идея если передаем приватную инфу требующую авторизации.

Comment: @eicto, согласен, но вопрос стоял о том как реализовать саму загрузку, какой вариант ему лучше подходит решит уже @Error.

Answer (score 1):

Обожаю эту статью: [Кроссдоменный AJAX](http://vremenno.net/js/crossdomain-ajax/)

p.s. или [хедарами](http://habrahabr.ru/post/114432/)